# Example of gitignore file for java

Tags: java, git, gitignore

Can you show me example of `.gitignore` file for java, that consider a lot of different files that are not included(jar, war, classpath, files that IDEA and other IDE generates and so on and on). I mean really big `.gitignore`.

What I currently have is

```
**/target/
/target/
*/target/*
.classpath
.project
.settings

# Package Files #
*.jar
*.war
*.ear

*.iml
*.idea
```

Comment: could anybody share file that he uses himself?

Comment: What you are asking is not simply about "Java".  It is highly related to the IDE, build tools, setting of tools etc that you are using.

Comment: Just one thing to comment: seems you are using Maven (from the `target/`).  Adding `*.jar, *.war, *.ear` are superfluous given that in a proper Maven project, such packaged output should be put under `target` directory.  You do not need to exclude them again.

Comment: https://www.gitignore.io/api/maven,java is what you want. If not, go to https://www.gitignore.io and select the IDE/Language combination you need.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can get sample java gitignore files at https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/master/Java.gitignore

Based on the comments , here is a gist of the sample gitignore class

```
*.class

# Mobile Tools for Java (J2ME)
.mtj.tmp/

# Package Files #
*.jar
*.war
*.ear

# virtual machine crash logs, see http://www.java.com/en/download/help/error_hotspot.xml
hs_err_pid*
```

Comment: no, that is not what I meant. That file includes only*.jar *.war *.ear and that  is pretty is. What about files that are generated by IDEA for example?

Comment: You may find the following link useful [Jetbrains Gitignore](https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/master/Global/JetBrains.gitignore)

Answer (score 26):

This .gitignore has other Java-related temp files added -

https://gist.github.com/dedunumax/54e82214715e35439227

```
##############################
## Java
##############################
.mtj.tmp/
*.class
*.jar
*.war
*.ear
*.nar
hs_err_pid*

##############################
## Maven
##############################
target/
pom.xml.tag
pom.xml.releaseBackup
pom.xml.versionsBackup
pom.xml.next
pom.xml.bak
release.properties
dependency-reduced-pom.xml
buildNumber.properties
.mvn/timing.properties
.mvn/wrapper/maven-wrapper.jar

##############################
## Gradle
##############################
bin/
build/
.gradle
.gradletasknamecache
gradle-app.setting
!gradle-wrapper.jar

##############################
## IntelliJ
##############################
out/
.idea/
.idea_modules/
*.iml
*.ipr
*.iws

##############################
## Eclipse
##############################
.settings/
bin/
tmp/
.metadata
.classpath
.project
*.tmp
*.bak
*.swp
*~.nib
local.properties
.loadpath
.factorypath

##############################
## NetBeans
##############################
nbproject/private/
build/
nbbuild/
dist/
nbdist/
nbactions.xml
nb-configuration.xml

##############################
## Visual Studio Code
##############################
.vscode/
.code-workspace

##############################
## OS X
##############################
.DS_Store
```

Answer (score 10):

check https://www.gitignore.io/.

If you want .gitignore file, pick up some from https://www.gitignore.io/api/java%2Cintellij

Comment: Thanks for the link. Very helpful!